# Displaying a part of page after an action is performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have piece of html code like this   :

```
  <p>Do you want a graph ?</p>
                <div class="selection spacing clearfix">
                    <input type="radio" name="graph" value="Yes">Yes<br> <input
                        type="radio" name="graph" value="No">No<br>
                </div>
```

and the next part like this :

```
<p>Which graphs do you want ?</p>           

                 <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Blocker">Blocker<br>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Critical">Critical<br>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Major">Major<br>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Minor">Minor<br>
```

I want the second part of the html to be displayed only if the user clicks yes in the first part. I'm trying to google it but didn't get much information on it. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: have you tried javascript code?if yes post it?

Comment: @Karthik so try something, e.g, try to search for: "click on element toggle other element jquery" in google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this can be acomplished with css only.

vote if you like that...

check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/nhwqD/

css:

```
div {
display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+div {
display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="graph" value="no" />
<input type="radio" name="graph" value="yes" />
<div> I am here only because u wanna graphs </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <p>Do you want a graph ?</p>
  <div class="selection spacing clearfix">
    <input type="radio" name="graph" value="Yes" class="js-show">Yes<br> 
    <input type="radio" name="graph" value="No" class="js-hide">No<br>
  </div>

  <div class="js-place">
    <p>Which graphs do you want ?</p>           
    <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Blocker">Blocker<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Critical">Critical<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Major">Major<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Minor">Minor<br>
  </div>
```

Now javascript with jQuery

```
var div = $(".js-place");
$(".js-show").click(function(){
  div.show();
});

$(".js-hide").click(function(){
  div.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanx bro ! I checked this one out but didn't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the second part in some block element like and give **display:none** property on it.

```
<div id="#checkBoxDiv" style="display:none">
<p>Which graphs do you want ?</p>           

                 <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Blocker">Blocker<br>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Critical">Critical<br>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Major">Major<br>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="graphs" value="Minor">Minor<br>
</div>
```

then using JS or jquery on select of radio button 'yes',you can change that property to **display:block** and it will get displayed on the screen

```
$('#checkBoxDiv').css('display','block');
```